# Strip everything from a string apart from a number and currency denominator

Tags: php, regex, explode

I have the following example strings:

```
The price is $54.00 including delivery
On sale for £12.99 until December
European pricing €54.76 excluding UK
```

From each of them I want to return only the price and currency denominator

```
$54.00
£12.99
€54.76
```

My though process is the have an array of currency symbols and search the string for each one and then capture just the characters before the space after that - however, $ 67.00 would then fail

So, can i run through an array of preset currency symbols, then explode the string and chop it at the next instance of a non numeric character that is not a . or , - or maybe with regex

Is this possible?

Comment: I'd say go with a regex otherwise you'll end up with a decent amount of code checking and shifting things.  Be wary of the alternate uses of `.` and `,`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In regex, `\p{Currency_Symbol}` or `\p{Sc}` represent any currency symbol.

However, [PHP supports](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) only the shorthand form `\p{Sc}` and `/u` modifier is required.

---

Using regex pattern

```
/\p{Sc}\s*\d[.,\d]*(?<=\d)/u
```

you will be able to match for example:

- $1,234
- £12.3
- € 5,345.01

---

If you want to use `.` as a decimal separator and `,` as a thousands delimiter, then go with

```
/\p{Sc}\s*\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?/u
```

---

Check **[this demo](http://ideone.com/oFJhc2)**.

Comment: `Currency_Symbol`, awesome! must remember this

Comment: @Ωmega Why does this fail? 
preg_match('/\p{Currency_Symbol}\s*\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?/u', $input, $match); $input is the string

Comment: @Ωmega Appreciated, brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

You could go for something like this:

```
preg_match('/(?:\$|€|£)\s*[\d,.-]+/', $input, $match);
```

And then find your currency and price inside `$match`.

Of course, you can generate that first part from an array of currency symbols. Just don't forget to escape everything:

```
$escapedCurrency = array_map("preg_quote", $currencyArray);
$pattern = '/(?:' . implode("|", $escapedCurrency) . ')\s*[\d,.-]+/';
preg_match($pattern, $input, $match);
```

Some possible improvement to the end of the pattern (the actual number):

```
(?:\$|€|£)\s*\d+(?:[.,](?:-|\d+))?
```

That will make sure that there is only one `.` or `,` followed by either `-` or only digits (in case your intention was to allow an international decimal separator).

If you only want to allow the comma to separate thousands, you could go for this:

```
(?:\$|€|£)\s*\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.(?:-|\d+))?
```

This will match the longest "correctly" formatted number (i.e. `$ 1,234.4567,123.456` -> `$ 1,234.4567` or `€ 123,456789.12` -> `€ 123,456`). It really depends on how accurate you want to go for.