# Divide string before integer value using php

Tags: php, regex, string, explode

I have some random type string and I want them to separate from each other.
My string is like these:

```
 1.  GPF#: AUDITKT0059 800,126.00
 2.  GPF#: IV EMP KK 8 58,971.00
 3.  GPF#: GAKU 000006 317,253.00
```

I want to get the GPF value but the issue is last values coming with string.I just want the value like `AUDITKT0059`,`IV EMP KK 8` and `GAKU 000006`.I tried by exploding with GPF and then space but this not the way it works.So any suggestion? Thanks
I tried like this :

```
$gpf = explode("GPF#:", $data[$c]);

             $gpfs = explode(" ", $gpf[1]);
             print_r($gpfs);
            echo " GPF# ".$gpfs[0]."<br />\n";
```

Comment: Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441125/strip-everything-from-a-string-apart-from-a-number-and-currency-denominator?rq=1

Comment: Do you mean this [**`GPF#:\s*(.*?)\s*[\d,.]+$`**](https://regex101.com/r/gmgfMq/1) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
_(.*)_
```

Note that I used `_` just to show a white space .

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/9MxwMz/2/)**

Php code

```
$re = '/ (.*) /';
$str = 'GPF#: AUDITKT0059 800,126.00
GPF#: IV EMP KK 8 58,971.00
GPF#: GAKU 000006 317,253.00';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Its likelihood to produce false matches, depending on input string.

Answer (score 0):

Here I use **Regular Expression** to extract data, please try

```
$data = [
    "GPF#: AUDITKT0059 800,126.00",
    "GPF#: IV EMP KK 8 58,971.00",
    "GPF#: GAKU 000006 317,253.00",
];
foreach ($data as $string) {
    $match = [];
    preg_match("/^GPF#: ([A-Z0-9 ]{11}) .*$/", $string, $match);
    echo "GPF#: " . $match[1], PHP_EOL;
}
```

The result will be

```
GPF#: AUDITKT0059
GPF#: IV EMP KK 8
GPF#: GAKU 000006
```